# Black socks and green socks

Tags: lateral-thinking, rhyme, probability

> *Some green socks, some black socks, their total is four.*
>  *Some green socks, some black socks, some socks on the floor.* 
> *The chance of getting two black ones, the chance of getting two black ones, that chance is a third.*
> *On the first draw, on the first draw, and there are no more draws, no more draws, no more draws.*
> *Some green socks, some black socks, some socks on the floor.*
> *What's the chance, what's the chance, of getting exactly one green sock, exactly one green sock, I wonder?*
> *And remember, and remember, their total is four!*
> *Some green socks, some black socks, some socks on the floor.*

Comment: Have you read [Are math-textbook-style problems on topic?](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2783/are-math-textbook-style-problems-on-topic) on meta?

Comment: Just for fun, @randal'thor, suppose the probability of 2 blacks socks had been 1/3...  that would not occur in a mathematics class and would require `lateral-thinking`

Comment: @TheBitByte Yes, and? The "basic maths exercise" close reason still exists. Questions like this aren't what PSE is for.

Comment: Looking forward to enjoying how `lateral` the `thinking` will get!

Comment: @Close voters, this question has been fixed/modified. Please review it now and let me know if there's anything more I can improve.

Answer (score 1):

**The latest edit to the question makes this answer invalid. It is in the process of being updated.**

> No chance of getting 2 green socks(!), if the probability of getting two black socks is 1/2. The latest edit to the question makes it 1/3, so this answer is in the process of being updated.

...because there are...

> ...3 black socks but only 1 green sock.

This was derived by using $b$ for the number of black socks,
so the probability of getting 2 would be...

> ... $1/2 ~ = ~ b/4 {\small\times} (b{-}1)/3 ~ = ~ b(b{-}1)/12 ~ = ~ 6/12$ ...

...which leaves only one possible value for $b$.

Even better than having 2 green socks, though,
is this straightforward way to verify this conclusion, thanks to
[Peregrine Rook](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/19765/peregrine-rook):

> Since you are dividing the four socks randomly into two groups of two
>  (the two that you take out and the two that you leave behind), there’s
>  a 50% probability that you select the green sock and a 50% probability
>  that you don’t. But you get two black socks if and only if the green
>  sock is one of the ones you leave in the box.

Comment: Here’s a slightly simpler way of doing the “check”: since you are dividing the four socks randomly into two groups of two (the two that you take out and the two that you leave behind), there’s a 50% probability that you select the green sock and a 50% probability that you don’t. But you get two black socks if and only if the green sock is one of the ones you leave in the box.